# Address Book Framework and POP, IMAP, or ActiveSync Contacts

Tags: iphone

Can the `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` be called to display Contacts from a  different account than the default?  For example, a gmail, or Exchange account?  I've read the `ABAddressBook` documentation and all I find is code below to the default Address Book on the iphone.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
```

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone doesn't store contacts like that. You may be able to access a user's GMail contacts through a GMail API, but if that's the case then you wouldn't be using the built-in address book. As of right now, the answer is no.